# Views filter criteria date field is greater than current date

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I have a overview page with different events. Now it shows all events which were created. But I will that it just shows all the future events.

The content type has a datefield for the eventdate. I selected the field_date_event by the filter criteria but there I can not enter the token [current-date] or a dateformat like d.m.y.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to choose the `Operator` **Is greater than or equal to**, and the `Value type` set to offset with value **Today**:

[image: future Date Filter]

This will include events happening today. If you want strictly from tomorrow you can choose **Is greater than** as the Operator.

Answer (score 3):

Add filter:

Operator "Is less than" value "today +24 hours" to remove future dated content if needed.

See: [Filter nodes by today's date](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292318/filter-nodes-by-todays-date/292323#292323)