# How to add filter criteria by current date in views

Tags: views, 9

I am using Drupal 9 and have a content type with a field "Publish until" (datetime).
I want to add a filter in views that it will compare the date in this field with current date.
I found a solution here for Drupal 8
[Views filter criteria date field is greater than current date](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273088/views-filter-criteria-date-field-is-greater-than-current-date/273133)

However, my screen looks a bit different:
[image]

To be more specific, I don't have a "Value type" which seems to be necessary in my case.
Am I missing any module that should be enabled?
Or is it related to the Drupal 9 itself?

If there is any another approach to solve this problem with filtering I will be glad to know it.

Comment: Are you sure this field is of type "Date" and not maybe of type "Timestamp"? Check this in your content type.

Comment: @StefanKorn Thank you for your advice. It is actually timestamp. I tried this filter with date field and it worked as expected. I will be more careful next time.